# How to create a command in vim that accesses the current filename?

Tags: vim

I would like to create an individual vim command that does the following:

1. save the current file
2. run the current file with python

Currently I have to do it like this:

`:w`

`:! python3 {filename}`

Instead, I would like to do this:

`:pyRun`

or something similar

Comment: `:set autowrite` and you can just do `:!python3 %` without having to `:w` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain commands with `|`. So

```
:w | ! python3 %
```

will save the buffer and run it with python3.

See `:help :bar` and `:help c_%` for more information.

You can create a command for this like:

```
:command PyRun execute 'w <bar> ! python3 %'
```

Note that custom commands in vim have to start with an uppercase letter.